# Using a function in Matlab

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

Very new to MATLAB and Im trying to use the FFT function. I got a video which showed me that a function and a normal m file is needed. Created that but now dont know how to call the function from the m file. Here's is the function:

`function [ X,freq ] = positiveFFT( x,Fs )
%This function takes data,and discards negatives only taking the
%positives,getting rid of complex values
%adopted from blinkdagger.com`

`N=length(x);`
`k=0:N-1;`
`T=N/Fs;`
`freq=k/T; %create the frequency range`
`X=fft(x)/N; %normalise the data`
`cutOff=ceil(N/2); %cut off frequency`
`X=X(1:cutOff);`
`freq=freq(1:cutOff);`

`end`

and the m-file:
`fo=4; %freqency of the sine wave(4cycles,4Hz)`
`Fs=100; %sampling rate`
`Ts=1/Fs; %sampling time interval`
`t=0:Ts:1-Ts;`
`n=length(t); %number of samples`
`y=2*sin(2*pi*fo*t);`
`[YfreqD,freqRng]=positiveFFT(y,Fs);`
`stem(freqRng,abs(YFreqD));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change

```
stem(freqRng,abs(YFreqD));
```

as

```
stem(freqRng,abs(YfreqD));
```

Comment: actually didnt notice that thanx alot...guess it was the pressure to hand in the assignment on time

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

@manny264

It looks like you ARE calling the function positiveFFT from within the m-file. the positiveFFT function in turn is calling the fft function of matlab.

[YfreqD,freqRng]=positiveFFT(y,Fs);

it is calling the function from within the "main". Not clear what else you expect it to do.